Creating an API monitoring system for APIs hosted inside a server
I have an external app A hosted on tomcat with an API endpoint "abc:5000/home" running on a Linux server.
I want to create a app/script that runs independently on the same server and monitors all traffic/requests made on "abc:5000/home" api.
The concept is quite similar to how spring actuators are used but since the actuators are configured in the same application, it is possible for the spring application to monitor traffic on it.
I went through multiple solutions available online but mostly all are related to packet capturing through either Tcpdump or wireshark on the externally excessible interface (eth0).
my expectations are quite similar to how spring actuators work but it is not using same deployer as of the applications.
PS - i am not sure is the solution is possible or not.
